# explicit bijection between ${[2n+1]\choose n+1}$ and ${[2n+1]\choose n}$ mapping $A$ to a subset of $A$

Tags: combinatorics, matching-theory

let ${A\choose k}=\{S\subseteq A: |S|=k\}$ and $[r]=\{1,\dots,r\}$. 
 Using Hall's marriage theorem one can prove there exists a bijection $f:{[2n+1]\choose n+1}\to{[2n+1]\choose n}$ so that $f(A)\subset A$ for all $A\in {[2n+1]\choose n+1}$. 
**Question**. is there an explicit simple construction of such an $f$ (or its inverse) ?